# How do I find the path to the .exe file that created a process?

Tags: windows, command-line, process

Preferably a command line tool to do this...

I understand that there is a program called tasklist.exe in Windows systems, and it has many powerful features to view processes currently running on the system.
Unfortunately it does not have the functionality to view the path of the .exe file that created or spawned the process in the first place.

I finally decided to take a tour of my system and I've noticed some shady looking processes and I want to check if they live in equally shady looking places on my system.

Any ideas?

Comment: a lot of service processes have screwy names. You can google for `wth.exe` and usually the first result is one of 10-20 websites that help you find malware, versus normal (but hidden) system services. The Powershell thiing below is good too! Good luck.

Comment: Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell.

Click Start -> Run, and type `powershell` to invoke Power Shell.

View all processes currently:

```
tasklist
```

Show full path of .exe file (Example command for Notepad++):

```
Get-Process notepad++ | Select-Object Path
```

You will see output:

### Path

C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe

Comment: I was looking for something more backward compatible, backward compatible with Windows XP and higher actually. Good answer though.